# Unsafe performance C# , remove long being cast to int to access array index

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, unsafe

Hi I got following code in C# unsafe where array is fixed

```
array[(int)(index)]
```

index is long (and has to be long for some reasons).. so I need to cast it to int in order to get access to array element. Is there a way to use pointers or some other combination of actions in unsafe code to prevent this cast cause index can have long value of 1 for example (and never exceeds int value obv)..
I feel that maybe unsafe pointers addition could prevent it from happening. I also feel this cast is not for free..and performance is the issue here. (exactly this line)
I also think its not possible but I ask just in case im mistaken.

Ok ill give some more detail , im doing some required logical operations on long preIndex like

> value = array[(int)((preIndex & mask ) >> 10)]

those operations are required and code is fairly minimalistic already. Only thing I can find to be optimizable is this cast from long to int, cause bitwise operations are required.

Thanks

Comment: A cast from long to int is insanely fast - what makes you think that this is a performance issue?

Comment: Wow actually fun part is , I removed this (int) explicit cast leaving it implicit and performance dropped by 18% O_o  I guess ill keep (int) even in unchecked context.. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a *trivial* cost converting from `long` to `int`, but I'm very sure that a: it **won't** matter in any sane code and b: it is unavoidable (arrays are accessed via `int` index; period). To show the **won't** matter:

```
static class Program
{
    static int GetSize() { return 10000; }
    static void Main() {

        int size = GetSize();
        int[] someData = new int[size];

        var watchInt32 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                someData[j]++;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) someData[j] = 0;
        watchInt32.Stop();
        long lSize = size;
        var watchInt64 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            for (long j = 0; j < lSize; j++)
            {
                someData[j]++;
            }
        }
        watchInt64.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("{0}ms vs {1}ms over {2} iterations",
            (int)watchInt32.ElapsedMilliseconds,
            (int)watchInt64.ElapsedMilliseconds, 5000 * size);
    }
}
```

I get:

> 162ms vs 215ms over 50000000 iterations

So unless your code does **nothing** except array access, this just isn't going to matter. At all. In any significant way.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but replace 5000 with 1000 billions and youll see difference I think. My code does 160 million operations per seconds and has to run for days.

Comment: I guess your right and its unevoidable , I think so too. I was just hoping for some magic way to ignore left bytes maybe or something, guess there is none.

Comment: You could perhaps try a union struct, but I expect that would be *slower*; tested: 155ms vs 245ms vs 316ms over 50000000 iterations

Comment: im not sure what you mean by union struct? just out of curiousity now, since its slower anyway ;)

Comment: @Valentin my point is; surely it does *something* else than just get/set array values by index; in most cases that *something* will completely dwarf array access (which is, to stress, very very very cheap)

Comment: @Valentin: `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] struct MyUnion { [FieldOffset(0)] public int i0; [FieldOffset(4)] public int i1; [FieldOffset(0)] public long l; }`

Answer (score 3):

In `unchecked` context (the default), the cast will just discard the unneeded MSBs, so there isn't a performance penalty. In checked context, it will throw an exception if the index range exceeds `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: so your saying this cast to int has no performance impact at all?

Comment: Yes, in `unchecked` context. So you may want to wrap it into `unchecked((int)index)`

Comment: im already in unchecked context however is there a link with proof for this? it simply sounds unreal..

Comment: You should be able to prove it by decompiling the code. Let me try.

Comment: @Valentin - this should be the difference between [conv.i4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_i4.aspx) and [conv.ovf.i4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_ovf_i4.aspx)

Comment: When `index` is of type `long`, the MSIL code inserts a `conv.i4` instruction, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to worry about a possible performance impact due to the conversion. Just look at the machine code generated by the JIT, they are identical for both the `int` and the `long` index:

x86, release mode, `int` index:

```
        var val = arr[idx];
00000059  cmp         ebx,dword ptr [edx+4] 
0000005c  jae         00000078 
0000005e  mov         esi,dword ptr [edx+ebx*4+8]
```

x86, release mode, casted `long` index:

```
        var val = arr[(int)idx];
0000005f  cmp         ebx,dword ptr [edx+4] 
00000062  jae         00000081 
00000064  mov         esi,dword ptr [edx+ebx*4+8]
```

x64, release mode, `int` index:

```
        var val = arr[idx];
00000060  movsxd      rcx,ebx 
00000063  mov         rax,qword ptr [rdi+8] 
00000067  cmp         rcx,3 
0000006b  jae         0000000000000080 
0000006d  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rdi+rcx*4+10h]
```

x64, release mode, `long` index:

```
        var val = arr[(int)idx];
00000061  movsxd      rcx,ebx 
00000064  mov         rax,qword ptr [rdi+8] 
00000068  cmp         rcx,3 
0000006c  jae         0000000000000080 
0000006e  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rdi+rcx*4+10h]
```

As Daniel Gehriger pointed out, the conv.i4 IL instruction doesn't need to be considered in the machine code, the 32 MSBs are simply dropped.

Comment: How would you comment the fact that when I remove (int) casts and leave them implicit performance drops from 110 million operations per second to 90 million? I removed 16 (int) casts inside my loop. This is very interesting though that machine code is the same, if it is the same , how comes there is a performance drop which you can see in answer I marked as answer for longs being cast to int?

Comment: Interesting question; have you looked at the disassembly (of your code)?

Answer (score -1):

The performance issue you see from that line is from the index lookup - is it a regular array, like object[] ? or did you implement the index property?

Comment: For your information, a dictionary lookup is **way** slower than a index lookup in an array.

Comment: its basic fixed (int* array= safeArray[0]) without anything special

Comment: @Øyvind: I might have been a bit fast on my answer - there is no doubt that index lookup is faster. I thought that the indexer maybe was on some class that implemented it - since that was stated as beeing slow(er) - it's not like there was a lot of context for this question :) If it is normal array access there is not a lot to be done. To optimize I would maybe look at loop unrolling or even the mono runtime with SIMD support if it's appropriate for the problem.

Comment: No problem. Just wanted to comment so other don't get confused here :) (for the record, the downvote is not by me)

Comment: @Øyvind: Fair enough - I removed the bad suggestion :)

Answer (score -1):

```
int count = 10000000;
            object [] a = new object[count];

            Stopwatch s1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (long i = 0; i < count; i++)
                a[i] = new object();
            s1.Stop();

            Stopwatch s2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                a[i] = new object();
            s2.Stop();       



            Debug.WriteLine(s1.ElapsedTicks + "  " + s2.ElapsedTicks);
```

> 3362502  3115428

So there is no significant impact.

Comment: interesting how you say theres no impact, while first version runs at least 7% slower ;)

Comment: Because if you switch their places - the result will also vary :). But you are right, a little of it should be considered.